# read number from UITextfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I need the user in the interface builder text field to enter a number and i want to read it as number i think the system read it as string and no output
here is my code if you can kindly assist

in the interface

```
{
IBOutlet UITextField *arr_values;}

@property (nonatomic ,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *arr_values;
```

and in the .m file

```
int inputNumber = [arr_values.text intValue]; 
NSLog(@"%@",inputNumber);
```

but no output when i enter # in the Interface builder
with thanks

Answer (score 3):

> You can  get value from textField like this.

```
float val=[txtField.text floatValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

replace the %@ by %d, as for an integer we have %d:
`NSLog(@"%d",inputNumber);`

As for the custom keyboard, in the viewDidLoad method add the line:

`[inputNumber setKeyboardType: UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];`

Comment: Do you input this textfield in view? @Oracle Oracle

Comment: i put it in the interface builder in view is that what u mean ? thnx